# Show MaterialUi snackbar by method

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to show message in material.ui by only call method not ading component to parent component (like toastify.js). So, I wrote example like below. But I couldn't call showSnack() method. How can I achieve this?

**Note: I don't want add component to demo js like < SnackbarHelper />. I only want show snackbar calling by function.**

[CODESANDBOX LINK](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-ghwzl?file=/demo.js)

**Demo.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import SnackHelper from "./snackHelper";

export default function PositionedSnackbar() {
  function showMessage() {
    console.log("I want call snackHelper.showSnack");
    // snackHelper.showSnack();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={() => showMessage()}>
        SHOW MESSAGE
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**snackbarHelper.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Snackbar from "@material-ui/core/Snackbar";

export default function SnackHelper() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    open: false
  });

  const { vertical, horizontal, open } = state;

  const showSnack = (newState) => () => {
    setState({ open: true, ...newState });
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setState({ ...state, open: false });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Snackbar
        anchorOrigin={{ vertical, horizontal }}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        message=""
        key={vertical + horizontal}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can checkout a package which is called notistack (https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack). It does exactly what you are trying to do. Basically you wrap around your whole application with a provider and you call the context method to trigger a snackbar. You could however implement your own if you decide to not use that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @dev_junwen. Yes, **toastify.js** and **notistack.js** doing this. But I don't want add addional package to my project. So, I want to write myself if it is possible.

Comment: Yes, and you should always place your snackbar on the main component. you cannot show something in html just with one simple function without target an element or adding element.

Comment: Thanks. But **toastify.js** and **notistack.js** can do this. How can they achieve this @b3hr4d

Comment: Yes, they can because u wrap your whole component inside their component, something like reducer + an action do work for you.

Comment: I need that doing like your said. But, I'm new at react. So, I 'll try to find example code which written someone else. Because, I can't achieve that. @b3hr4d

Comment: Yes, should be good, learn more about making reducer and context from react docs, by using them you can make global state and action. you can make anything just by calling an action. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution in this article for same thing what I was looking. Only difference is, this is for confirmation dialog and written by typescript. But, it can be easily changed to toast message by javascript. https://dev.to/dmtrkovalenko/the-neatest-way-to-handle-alert-dialogs-in-react-1aoe

You can get working example code https://codesandbox.io/s/neat-dialogs-3h5ou?from-embed=&file=/src/ConfirmationService.tsx